# Resistance of a Wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, conductors

> The resistivity of iron is $10\times10^{-8}\,\text{ohm-meter}$. A wire made of iron of length 15 m, and diameter 2.9 mm,will have a resistance of ___ ohms.

I calculated it using $R = \text{resitivity * length / area} = 0.227$ ohms, but apparently the answer key claims the answer is 0.182 ohms. What step did I mess up on?

UPDATE: To close off on this; I have spoken to my professor and he has confirmed that this was indeed a typo on his answer key.

Comment: someone pls help, ive recalculated 10 times and I don't see a mistake on my method.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Comment: I am not trying to ask for the answer per se, but am asking how my use of the theorem regarding Resistivty was incorrectly used or not. Asking "someone to do my homework" was not my intention.

Comment: it's more the "check my work" aspect here than the "do it for me". Also, I removed that image because it's not at all needed, considering I copied the content to a searchable text.

Comment: depending on your value for pi, you made a rounding error. I get 0.22709...

Comment: In order to answer the question "What step did I mess up on?", we need to know what your steps were.  In the future, if you ask a question on this site, you should explain your steps or your question will get closed.  As it is, it's not hard to see that you assume a round wire; the answer key appears to assume that it is square.

Comment: @Mike ok so in the assumption that the diameter refers to the "diameter of a square" :  The length of the sides of the square would be 2.9mm/sqrt(2). So Area = side^2  and plugging into the formula for R =resitivity * length / area  and using the aforementioned values of resistivty and length  would yield a resistance of  approximately 0.357 ohms

Comment: or if you were instead referring to a circle inscribed inside of square in which case the resistance would still be R = 0.178 ohms. Close but does not land on 0.182 ohms

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know you calculated the resistance correctly. Is this how you did it?
\begin{align}
R&=\frac{\rho l}{A} \\
&=\frac{(10\cdot 10^{-8})(15)}{\pi(1.45\cdot 10^{-3})^2} \\
&= 0.227 \Omega
\end{align}

Even using approximations of $\pi$ like $\frac{22}{7}$ or $3.14$, you should get  the same answer. The program you are taking the test on must be defect.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation on my answer to this; apparently some people misunderstood me as asking someone to do homework that I didn't do. I'll be asking the professor to look over the answer key, and let you know back here whatever the case is.